# htaccess rule to redirect root and rewrite all queries to another site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My domain is s1.example.com I want to rewrite all GET & POST to test.com/
I got the same done using the following rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://test.com/$1 [P]
```

But whenever there is a query for root, that is when user simply visits
http://s1.example.com/, the root of test.com shouldn't be served, rather the user should be redirected to issue a query, goTest.action

In other words, I want the DocumentRoot of s1.example.com to be a query, which is eventually handled by the rewrite rule above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your regex to `.+` and have a new rule for root page:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://test.com/$1 [P]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /goTest.action [L]
```